# Can I define array of strings and undefined in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have defined the following array in typescript: `let ids: string[] = [];`. Then when I try to push an id (which might be undefined) I have a compilation error: `ids.push(id);` gives me the following compilation error:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Can I create array of strings and undefined?

Comment: `let ids: (string | undefined)[] = [];`

Comment: What does your tsconfig looks like?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes:

```
let ids: (string | undefined)[] = [];
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the underlying issue. OP might have enabled the strict compiler flag which is resulting in this behavior.

Comment: Rolled back the previous suggested edit to this answer as it doesn't work in latest Typescript (4.7) & even if it did, would've been different: `[string] | undefined` rather than `[string|undefined]`.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you may have enabled the `strict` or `strictNullChecks` flag in your compiler config (either through the command line when you call `tsc` or in the `tsconfig.json` file).

> In strict null checking mode, the null and undefined values are not in the domain of every type and are only assignable to themselves and any (the one exception being that undefined is also assignable to void).
>   [[1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)]

As an example we can reproduce this using this sample code,

```
let ids: string[] = [];
let x: string | undefined;
x = Math.random() > 0.5 ? undefined : 'hello';
ids.push(x);
```

Here the compiler can't tell if `x` will be `undefined` or a `string`. (Note if you do `x = 'hello'`, then the compiler **can** statically check that `x` is not `undefined` at runtime)

We'll compile this with the `strict` flag enabled (which also enables the `strictNullChecks` flag)

We get the following compiler error

```
src/main.ts:4:10 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

4 ids.push(x);
           ~
```

So you may want to either define the `ids` variable as `(string | undefined)[]` as another answer suggests or consider disabling the strict flags.

Another possible solution is to use the `!` (
[Non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator)) operator to bypass the compiler (but you're intentionally ignoring a potential bug in many situations by using this since the compiler can no longer help you),

```
ids.push(x!);
```